# Threaded OpenBlas benchmark slower than system blas?

Tags: parallel-computing, lapack, blas

I'm not sure if I did something wrong or if I just didn't understand the concept of an optimized BLAS.

I'm a FEM engineer trying to optimize my setup on a small cluster computer (six nodes). I'm building everything on open source tools. My aim is to use a robust setup which allows me to manage large mechanical simulations. 
After finally compiling my programs using MPI I'm reading the using an optimized BLAS will help me further pushing down calculation time.

I installed **OpenBlas** and built **Lapack 3.4.2**. The results of the lapack benchmarks were surprising. They are fastest with the system (unoptimzed) BLAS and the run time increases with increasing number of threads specified (`export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=i`). The same is true for *scalapack*. Furthermore, `i>16` doesn't seem to utilize more than `16` threads, although I have `32` available on this machine. That's ok, because I want some to run a couple of MPI processes (4?) on one node anyways, but I find it suspicious.

I'm a beginner and don't know where to start digging from here. Can someone give me a hint? I have a pastebin of the `i=32` log [here](http://pastebin.com/BQATuymz).

```
OpenBLAS build complete.
OS               ... Linux
Architecture     ... x86_64 
BINARY           ... 64bit
C compiler       ... GCC  (command line : gcc)
Fortran compiler ... GFORTRAN  (command line : gfortran)
Library Name     ... libopenblas_sandybridgep-r0.2.5.a (Multi threaded; Max num-threads is 32)
```

Lapack 3.4.2 make.inc (changes from default)

```
 BLASLIB = /path/to/libopenblas.a -lpthread
```

-- **EDIT:** (more information because of @Aron Ahmadia's comments)

- [system BLAS log](http://pastebin.com/ATaUNti4)
- [`i=1` log](http://pastebin.com/fbNYLV7S)
- [`i=32` log](http://pastebin.com/BQATuymz)
- CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
- `blas-devel-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64`
- `gcc` version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) (same for `gfortran`).
- `MemTotal: 198202172 kB`

  ```
  $ grep "Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 0 @ 2.90GHz" /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l 
  32.
  ```

Comment: What Linux distribution are you running (release number, etc...), what CPUs are on your system, and what version of the compilers are you using?  The system BLAS on many distributions is not necessarily a poorly tuned one, but I agree that your results are surprising.

Comment: I'm puzzled.  The tuned OpenBLAS should be much faster than the RPM package you have installed, particularly on a single core.  Can you provide the benchmarks that you ran as well as their timing?  Was the machine otherwise idle when you ran the tests?

Comment: I'll need to do the timing. What time is desired, bash `time` or `/usr/bin/time`? machines are idle. [This](http://pastebin.com/ATaUNti4) is the log for the system BLAS.

Comment: Ahh, it looks like you are running verification tests as opposed to performance benchmarks.  I'm guessing that the wall time here is mostly coming from the time it takes to load each program and execute it, as opposed to the actual time spent in a single problem.  I actually have not benchmarked BLAS/LAPACK in awhile, but you are looking to run a larger problem that should take your CPU a minute or so to solve.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Perhaps something from here? http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/

Comment: Absolutely, just download [HPL](http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/hpl/) and off you go :)  Report back if those numbers make sense and I'll summarize this discussion into an answer (it's a good question, and I'm sure other people will run into this issue in the future).

Comment: @Sebastian How are you using MPI? What dense computations are you doing in your FEM analysis?

Comment: @Jed Brown - just a hint, all comments on posts automatically flag the original poster.  You only need to use @ when trying to get the attention of somebody else.

Comment: @JedBrown I'm currently using MPI for solving $A.x=b$ using conjugate gradient with MPI paralleled `MUMPS` as a single precision preconditioner. At a later stage I also want to use `PetSC` with an algebraic MG (ML/hypre..). It's for large 3d mechanical simulations.

Comment: Please note that 32 threads on a hyperthreading enabled system run on 16 cores with a single FPU each, so it is correct to not have more than 16 OpenBlas threads.

Comment: Final comment: as pointed out by @AronAhmadia the matrices in the dataset of your verification tests (which are not a benchmark) are way too small to give significative figures for multithreaded BLAS. With $M=N=16$ it is no surprise that multithreading OpenBlas is slower than ATLAS.

Comment: @StefanoM thanks for these additional comemnts.

Comment: The FEM for $3D$ solid mechanics gives raise to sparse matrices, as we all know. To effectively exploit dense BLAS you have to switch to a supernodal approach, but, in my own experience, rarely supernodes are big enough to justify multithread BLAS. If the supernodes are very small you will not be able to exploit effectively the higher throughput of OpenBLAS or MKL even on a single thread: you should pay more attention to low overhead (setup and call) implementations than high throughput ones. Maybe @JedBrown was also hinting in this direction with his comment.

Comment: @AronAhmadia Thanks for your hint on HPL. I just finished the benchmarks and they clearly show that `openblas` is faster. If you can summarize this in an answer I'll accept it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenBLAS is designed as a library to perform effectively for the most common computationally challenging problems that arise in scientific computing, linear algebra problems that take minutes or longer to solve.  As @Stefano and @JedBrown hint in the comments, you are not necessarily likely to depend heavily on the performance of your BLAS library for the performance of your FEM solver, and it is more important to use a freely available robust software framework such as [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/), (potentially with [deal.II](http://www.dealii.org) or [FEniCS](http://fenicsproject.org/) as a friendlier FEM interface above), to develop your software.  I can think of very few situations where I would not recommend using a high-level FEM and linear algebra framework to develop and execute your code.

In this case, you are not seeing a difference in performance because you are using the validation tests for LAPACK, which solves considerably smaller problems.  The run time of launching the processes from the shell and loading them dynamically are confounding your performance measurements.

As suggested in the comments, you will notice a sharp relative improvement in performance by measuring larger problems.